# Allow https requests in docker environment

Tags: docker, spring-boot, ssl, https, docker-compose

I have a Spring-boot application running on aws, where I have port 443 open and the application configured to receive https requests, and it works fine this way:

properties:

```
server:
    port: 8443
    ssl: 
        key-store: '/etc/letsencrypt/live/app.testapp.com/keystore.p12'
        key-store-password: 'password'
        keyStoreType: PKCS12
        keyAlias: tomcat
security:
    require-ssl: true
```

I just installed and configured docker with docker-compose on the server and since then, when I build and deploy the application, I can only do http requests for my endpoints, https does not work. How do I release https requests for my application? Can someone help me?

Dockerfile:

```
FROM openjdk:8-jdk-alpine
EXPOSE 443
VOLUME /tmp
ADD target/testapp-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar app.jar
RUN sh -c 'touch /app.jar'
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom -Drun.profiles=prod","-jar","/app.jar"]
```

docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '3'
services:
    rabbitmq:
      image: "rabbitmq"
      hostname: "rabbitmq"
      environment:
        RABBITMQ_ERLANG_COOKIE: "SWQOKODSQALRPCLNMEQG"
        RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_USER: "test"
        RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_PASS: "test"
      ports:
        - "15672:15672"
        - "5672:5672"
      labels:
        NAME: "rabbitmq"
    testapp-backend-prod:
        build: .
        ports:
            - "8443:8443"
        depends_on:
            - redis
            - rabbitmq
    redis:
        image: redis
```

Comment: How does HTTPS not work? What error messages / behavior are you seeing?

Answer (score 0):

Your server is configured for port 8443 while all of the docker configurations are configured for port 443. Fixing that should solve the issue.

Comment: His compose file is mapping `8443:8443`?

Comment: Yet his dockerfile is exposing 443

Comment: Which doesn't matter at all.

Comment: Yes @johnharris85: ports: - "8443:8443"

Comment: @YaronIdan How do I change this setting in docker?

Comment: @johnharris85 is right, exposing the correct port would not affect your situation. Sorry for the wrong answer, I'll delete it.